# Difference betwee the set resulting from FILTER and the set resulting from {} with respect to aggregate

Tags: excel, excel-formula, mdx

I'm building/maintaining a fairly large report at present that relies on Cube formulae in Excel (yes it's horrible, and yes there isn't really another option).

One area which has always been somewhat of a pain is `CubeSet`s which have typically been specified long-hand by specifying every member of the set, e.g.

```
CUBESET(
    __CurrentSheet_Connection__,
    "{
      [Geography].[CountryHierarchy].[Asia].[China], 
      [Geography].[CountryHierarchy].[Asia].[Japan]
     }"
)
```

Which of course is pretty difficult to maintain whenever members change names, or worse, when hierarchies do (e.g. if we eliminate Asia, and just go straight to countries).

One approach which is somewhat more straightforward to maintain is to try to use `FILTER` instead along with some text parsing to get a set. Unfortunately, this doesn't work because when Excel converts the formulae into queries, it passes sets into the `AGGREGATE` function.

For some reason, whereas

```
WITH MEMBER [D].[H].[XL_51] AS AGGREGATE({[D].[H].[M1], [D].[H].[M2]})
```

works,

```
WITH MEMBER [D].[H].[XL_51] AS AGGREGATE(
    FILTER(
        [D].[H].Children,
        INSTR("|M1||M2||M3|", "|" & [D].[H].CurrentMember.Name & "|", 0)
    )
)
```

doesn't, when the resultant set is passed into a `CUBEVALUE` formula.

Can anyone tell me, firstly, why the second doesn't work, and ideally, if there is a way to make it (or something similar) work.

EDIT: Realised that I had an error with with the statement Excel converts a cubeset into. I had `SET`, it uses `MEMBER` for sets (and aggregates them together).

EDIT2: Added that I am trying to use the members to obtain values via `CUBEVALUE()` formulae.

Comment: how are you using `CUBESET(` with only one argument?

Comment: I agree that the behaviour is inconsistent. I would avoid using a set as a member_expression argument. If you want to use a member_expression argument then just create a member first

Comment: Easier said than done - I have no control over the cube itself, and members are usually too ad-hoc to push those who do to create them in any reasonable amount of time.

Comment: I've detailed, in my answer, a "better" way for you to be able to create your own members in the spreadsheet. Aslong as there is a pivot using the same connection then I think using the built in tools for creating sets and aggreggated custom members is a better approach.

Comment: did you find an answer to your question in the end?

Comment: Not really - though I found a workaround involving first retrieving the set via Filter, then iterating the using CubeRankedMember (in VBA), and then retrieving the same set in the form that works. I'd still be interested in knowing the actual reason why `Aggregate` works with actual sets but not with `FILTER` based sets, but for the time being, I've got a route that works...

Answer (score 2):

You can include any expression in the `CubSet` function that is valid `mdx` and returns a `set`. Some examples:

```
{}
.members
.allmembers
filter
union
intersect
...
```

You can find all the definitions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145970.aspx

I'm very surprised this actually works:

`WITH SET [XL_51] AS AGGREGATE({[D].[H].[M1], [D].[H].[M2]})`

...reason being that `Aggregate` is generally used to create a calculated member rather than a custom set. So I'm assuming somewhere along the lines the technology is being kind to you and changing this into a single member set.
This is more of a typical way of using `Aggregate`::

`WITH MEMBER [D].[H].[XL_51] AS AGGREGATE({[D].[H].[M1], [D].[H].[M2]})`

`Filter` is a iterative mdx function so should be saved for special occasions i.e. it is potentially slow!

So your second snippet would be better as a calculated member also (assuming you really want to aggregate the members found by Filter together:

```
WITH MEMBER  [D].[H].[XL_51] AS AGGREGATE(
    FILTER(
        [D].[H].Children,
        INSTR("|M1||M2||M3|", "|" & [D].[H].CurrentMember.Name & "|", 0)
    )
)
```

If you actually want a custom set then don't bother with `Aggregate`:

```
WITH SET [XL_51] AS 
    FILTER(
        [D].[H].Children,
        INSTR("|M1||M2||M3|", "|" & [D].[H].CurrentMember.Name & "|", 0)
    )
```

---

**Edit**

To use the `CUBESET` function against `AdvWrks`both of the following return a set of two members:

```
=CUBESET("AdvWrksConnection",
    "{
    [Geography].[Country].[Canada]
   ,[Geography].[Country].[Germany]
  }"
)
```

...this is the variant using `Filter`:

```
=CUBESET("AdvWrksConnection",
    "Filter
  (
    [Geography].[Country].Children
   ,
      Instr([Geography].[Country].CurrentMember.Member_Caption ,'germ' )
    OR 
      Instr([Geography].[Country].CurrentMember.Member_Caption ,'ada' )
  )"
)
```

If I then use the xl cell containing this set as a `Member_expression` argument for the `CUBEVALUE` function then the simple `{}` notation returns a value, whereas pointing at the cells which uses the filter function means `CUBEVALUE does not return a value. Neither cell contains a`member_expression` so, for me, the expected behaviour would be an error for both scenarios.

I'd avoid this implicit aggregation and conversion from set to member, that xl seems to be doing, by explicitly calculating the member myself. You can use the menus found here:

--> PIVOTTABLE TOOLS
--> ANALYZE
--> OLAP TOOLS

Then create a custom member that is the aggregation of a custom set. These new members that you create can be used directly in `CUBEVALUE` functions e.g.

1 Create set:

[image]

2 Aggregate the named set:

[image]

3 Use it in a formula:

```
=CUBEVALUE("AdvenWorksConnection","[Geography].[Country].[All Geographies].[aggregatedQuuq] ",L$5)
```

Comment: Might be me being unclear with my question - I don't use `Aggregate` - Excel does behind the scenes. That said, think I might have made a mistake in exactly what it's doing - think they use `WITH MEMBER [D].[H].[XL_51] AS AGGREGATE(<ExactlyWhatWasInTheCubeSetHere>)`, not `WITH SET ...`. Will update the question once I've checked...

Comment: @tobriand if you use your `filter(...)` inside a cubeset function is it returning a set ok? You can test by placing a `cubesetcount` function in the cell next to it.... it should return the numbers of expected members if filter is working ok.

Comment: @tobriand also this is strange `INSTR("|M1||M2||M3|", "|" & [D].[H].CurrentMember.Name & "|", 0)` ... what is its purpose?

Comment: It's definitely returning a set; it's just that that set doesn't work when used in CUBEVALUEs. The purpose of the pipe delineation is because sometimes I need to slice member names - e.g. when there is a code at the front - and I want to distinguish between e.g. 123 and 123A (don't want 123 when I'm targeting 123A).

Comment: @tobriand nice to try and help but your question just keep expanding: original question says nothing of the function `CUBEVALUE`

Comment: @tobriand This is the definition of the `CUBEVALUE` function `CUBEVALUE(connection, [member_expression1], [member_expression2], …)` .... no mention of any Set expressions ... so depends how you are relating the set to this function

Comment: @tobriand we need to see what you are doing with these functions. I've used cube functions extensively but without seeing the syntax you've used it is a little tricky to help

Comment: Any member expression can be either a `CUBEMEMBER` cell or a `CUBESET` cell - or at least this has worked for me typically. The resultant MDX query for such a cell uses `Aggregate` on sets (presumably to convert them into members), and uses the indexed versions of actual members, passing everything into a single axis and just pulling out the value. Basically, where cubesets are passed of the first form, it works, but not using `Filter`

Comment: @tobriand sounds interesting: I'll play with this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the walkthrough for Excel aggregated members - may well play with this. That said, I'm reluctant to lean too heavily on it because of this: https://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2014/04/01/create-session-cube-and-disk-usage/ . Think I could get away with it for one workbook, but needs to be played with CAREFULLY. I think I may have a formula-based approach to convert a set though. It's a pain, but might work, given that `CubeRankedMember` does return the actual member index, meaning it should be possible to iterate over these and generate a set. Possible use for Excel4 macros!

Comment: If you're interested in the Microsoft way of using these functions then try this walkthrough - it's excellent: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NewZealand/2013/DBI304